# Getting error while creating the new object of internet explorer application

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I am running the PowerShell script from server machine on destination machine.

The statement `$ie=new-object -ComObject internetexplorer.application` is throwing following exception.

> New-Object: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.

It will be working fine if I run the script on server machine itself. So why it will be giving problem on remote machine.

Comment: How are you connecting remotely? PowerShell remoting? PSEXEC? Remote desktop? VNC? WMI? DCOM? More context please.

Comment: I am connecting via PSEXEC.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run the command locally on the *remote* host (e.g. after logging in via RDP)?

Comment: No, the script is running successfully when I run it on remote machine locally.

Answer (score -1):

Try running your script as **administrator**.